# Parse HTML to edit links

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to parse an HTML file ([demo.html](http://pastebin.com/P54pNvLY) to make all relative links absolute. Here is how I try to do this in Python script -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('demo.html', 'r')
html_text = f.read()
f.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    for x in a.attrs:
        if x == 'href':
            temp = a[x]
            a[x] = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg" + temp
for a in soup.findAll('link'):
    for x in a.attrs:
        if x == 'href':
            temp = a[x]
            a[x] = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg" + temp
for a in soup.findAll('script'):
    for x in a.attrs:
        if x == 'src':
            temp = a[x]
            a[x] = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg" + temp
f = open("demo_result.html", "w")
f.write(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8"))
```

However, the output file [demo_result.html](http://pastebin.com/KRkxAJ4M) contains many unexpected changes. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ddtabmenu.js" />  
/***********************************************
* DD Tab Menu script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* + Drop Down/ Overlapping Content- 
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/   
</script>
```

changes to

```
 <script src="http://www.esplanade.com.sg/scripts/ddtabmenu.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>
  /***********************************************
   * DD Tab Menu script- (c) Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
   * + Drop Down/ Overlapping Content- 
   * This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
   * Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
   ***********************************************/
```

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks and warmest regards.

Comment: It is working fine at my end.

Comment: @user1471175 - What do you mean by that? Is it converting just the links and not changing other parts of the HTML like I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Sorry i was looking for wrong error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams beautiful soup 4 is giving problem 
just Downgrade Beautifult soup to version3 
your problem will be solved

```
import  BeautifulSoup      #This is version 3 not version 4
f = open('demo.html', 'r')
html_text = f.read()
f.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html_text)
print soup.contents
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    for x in a.attrs:
        if x == 'href':
            temp = a[x]
            a[x] = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg" + temp
for a in soup.findAll('link'):
    for x in a.attrs:
        if x == 'href':
            temp = a[x]
            a[x] = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg" + temp
for a in soup.findAll('script'):
    for x in a.attrs:
        if x == 'src':
            temp = a[x]
            a[x] = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg" + temp
f = open("demo_result.html", "w")
f.write(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks @user1471175 :D That did the trick. I have edited the code a bit though to get rid of the encoding/decoding errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is alittle messy. You have closed `script` tag and you are closing it again

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ddtabmenu.js" /></script>
```

It breaks DOM. Just remove `/` from the end of `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ddtabmenu.js" />`

Comment: Honest question, isn't BeatifulSoap expected to deal with broken HTML?

Comment: True this is a problem with Beautiful soup version 4 , version 3 works fine

Comment: @twil I agree that it is messy. However, I do not have control over the HTML since I am trying to crawl a web page. Of course, I could parse the HTML to make it better, but again, I would prefer if I don't have to :)

Comment: I think there is no need in pre or post parsing. If beautifulsoup3 feets your needs then stick with it. If you want to use bs4 you could try different [parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, regressing to BeautifulSoup 3 removes the problem. Also, adding the url like that will be problematic with html anchors and javascript references, so I changed the code:

```
import re
import BeautifulSoup

with open("demo.html", "r") as file_h:
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(file_h.read())

url = "http://www.esplanade.com.sg/"
health_check = lambda x: bool(re.search("^(?!javascript:|http://)[/\w]", x))
replacer = lambda x: re.sub("^(%s)?/?" % url, url, x)

for soup_tag in soup.findAll(lambda x: x.name  in ["a", "img", "link", "script"]):

    if(soup_tag.has_key("href") and  health_check(soup_tag["href"])):
        soup_tag["href"] = replacer(soup_tag["href"])

    if(soup_tag.has_key("src") and health_check(soup_tag["src"])):
        soup_tag["src"] = replacer(soup_tag["src"])

with open("demo_result.html", "w") as file_h:
    file_h.write(soup.prettify().encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to improve my code. But I am not very familiar with regular expressions. So, I will be really grateful if you could also please explain in detail what patterns those regexes are expecting to catch. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Sure, health_check is a function that takes a href string and checks whether: a) it does not begin with either "javascript:" or "http://"; and b) it starts with a forward slash or a alphanumeric character. replacer is a function that performs a regex substitution on the href or src strings; it replaces from the beginning of the string up to and including: a) the url (if it exists) and b) a forward slash (if it exists), with the url itself.